# Selecting value corresponding with MAX value of a group

Tags: mysql, oxid

**I am trying to get the OXSEOURL of my OXSEO table.**

*Structure:*
oxobjectid | oxseourl | oxparams

*Data:*
http://imageshack.com/a/img268/7443/3xr4.png
http://imageshack.com/a/img42/315/8bdu.png
My deepest SEO URL always has the higher value in OXPARAMS field.
Only the numeric values, the others are never count..

*Return should be:*

http://imageshack.com/a/img29/8404/4jbv.png

I found a solution yesterday, but it was very slow, now I am trying to get a faster way to do it.
So I would like to get the oxseourl  for the same oxobjectid with the max oxparams value.
I have more than 330.000 rows, so every ms counts..

I only have to select the urls for products staring with "tbproduct_" objectid.

*My query:*

```
SELECT seo2.oxseourl, seo2.oxobjectid, seo2.oxparams
FROM oxseo AS seo2
JOIN (
      SELECT oxobjectid, 
          MAX(oxparams) AS maxparam
      FROM    oxseo
      GROUP BY
          oxobjectid
     ) AS usm
     ON usm.maxparam = seo2.oxparams
WHERE seo2.oxobjectid LIKE '%tbproduct_%'
    AND seo2.oxparams REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'
```

But this returns the same rows for the products.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Aren't you missing part of your JOIN condition!?!

Comment: which part do you mean?

Comment: If the oxobjectid begins with `tbproduct` then you can use `WHERE seo2.oxobjectid LIKE 'tbproduct_%'` which allows an index to be used.

Comment: The bit that relates the objectid of seo2 with the objectid of usm

Comment: But really the first step needs to be to tidy up your data. Trying to search that this way is going to be so inefficient - and liable to lead to errors.

Comment: ON usm.maxparam = seo2.oxparams, usm.oxobjectid = seo2.oxobjectid ?

Comment: I cannot remove the other lines, because they are used in the shop.

Comment: Could you explain, maybe am missing something - you wrote: `Only the numeric values, the others are never count.. `, but the inner subquery takes into acount all values, not only numeric, see this example on SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d04b9/2

Comment: yeah right, we could place the oxseo.oxparams REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$' into the subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit optimized, and a lot faster:

```
SELECT seo.oxseourl, seo.oxobjectid, MAX(seo.oxparams)
FROM oxseo AS seo
WHERE seo.oxobjectid LIKE 'tbproduct_%' AND seo.oxparams REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'
GROUP BY seo.oxseourl, seo.oxobjectid
```